# Using NextJS, How Do I Create Nested Dynamic Paths With MongoDB Through getStaticProps and getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

so Im trying to get NextJS dynamic paths and I just cant figure it out. Sorry if this gets long, I will try to be as detailed as I can.

Im trying to make an ecommerce app using NextJS, the folder architecture is something like this:
Home / [ShopID] / Categories / [CategoryName] / [ProductName]

The MongoDB setup is something like this

```
{ShopID: <given mongodb id>,
ShopName: <Shop Name>
ShopCategories: {
Category1: {
CategoryDetails: <Pairs for category name, id, etc>,
CategoryProducts: {
Product1:{
ProductDetails: <Pairs for product name, id, etc>,}
}}}}
```

Currently, I am trying to make a version of the site for the shop owners to be able to add categories, products, and such.

The goal is to make something like this:
"/" = From the "/" page a button can be clicked to go to a /[ShopID] from the db (for now it will just be set up as a button since Im not trying to make authentication yet, then it leads to a dashboard page.

"/[ShopID]" = This is just a dashboard with buttons pointing to different parts so the "Categories and Products" button is here. Once clicked it will send you to "/[ShopId]/categories"

"/[ShopID]/categories" = So here it will contain React Component Buttons which have each category's picture, name, etc. which once clicked will lead to "/[ShopID]/categories/[CategoryName]"

"/[ShopID]/categories/[CategoryName]" = So here it will contain React Component Buttons for each Product which will then lead to "/[ShopID]/categories/[CategoryName]/[ProductName]"

Some of the relevant current code:

```
"/"
<Link href=""><div><h1>To home</h1></div></Link>
```

Initially I hardcoded the /[ShopID] Link paths to just be "/id" so Im not sure how the Link href="" should be setup.

```
"/[ShopID]"
import HomepageButton from "../../components/homepage/Homepage-Button"

<main className="maincontainer">
<HomepageButton item="home-category" label="Categories & Products"></HomepageButton>
```

The HomepageButton stuff is put below, am I supposed to put a getStaticProps and Paths here? The other problem I have is is it possible to pass down the collected MongoDb Data from here down through the components chain? It doesn't seem like it?
If I can't then do I have to call getStatic on each page then filter through it using data collected from useRouter?

```
HomepageButton Component

import Link from "next/link";
import { Fragment, use } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


function HomepageButton(props) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const shopId = router.query.givenid
  return (<Fragment>
    <Link href={{pathname: "/[givenid]/categories", query: { givenid: 'id' },}}>
      <h2>{props.label}</h2>
    </Link>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
export default HomepageButton;
```

The { givenid: 'id' } is just what I hardcoded it to be setup, some of the problems I had here will be put in the What did you try section.
When I later tried to get the params in useRouter within the getStatics, I forget what the error was but it doesnt look like useRouter can be done within getStatic?
I am also unsure as to how this should be structured.
query: { givenid: 'id' },}}> especially when stuff gets nested further down the line.

```
"/[ShopID]/categories"
<section className="category-container">
        {dummycategs.map((categ, index) => {
          return (
            <Category
              items={categ.category}
              key={index}
            ></Category>
          );
        })}
      </section>
```

The dummycategs is what I initially set up, more of my issues here will be put in the what did you try section for people who may have the same problem as me in the future.
Again, one of the main issues I am unsure of is how the data from above can be passed down as props. Can that be done?

```
Category Component
function Category(props){

    const {categoryName, categoryImage, categoryDescription, categoryProducts} = props.items
    const router = useRouter()
    const shopId = router.query.givenid

    const value = JSON.stringify(categoryProducts)
    // console.log(value)

    function sendData(){
        Router.push({
            pathname: "/[givenid]/categories/[categoryname]", query: { givenid: 'id', categoryname: categoryName, givenProducts: value}
        })
    }

    return <div className="category" onClick={sendData}>
    
        <img src={categoryImage} className="category-img"></img>
        <div className="category-content">
        <h2 className="heading-secondary category-name">{categoryName}</h2>
        <h3 className="heading-tertiary"> {categoryDescription}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This part is probably very wrong, I will go into more detail in the what did you try section.

That is pretty much it, I don't know how to set up the structure for getStaticProps and Paths. I did some testing and this is how I setup my getStaticProps, it seems to work but am I missing something?

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"

export async function getStaticProps(){
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
    const db = client.db()
    const shopsCollection = db.collection("shops")

    const shops = await shopsCollection.find().toArray()

    client.close()

    return {
        props: {
            shops: shops.map(shop => ({
                name: shop.name,
                data: shop.shopData,
                id: shop._id.toString()
            }))
        },
        revalidate: 1
    }
}
```

What did I try Section:

For those that may encounter similar issues to me, it seems like you can't pass down data through useRouter.
When I was trying to get the categories button to work, I was using Dummy Data and not MongoDb data.

```
function Category(props){

    const {categoryName, categoryImage, categoryDescription, categoryProducts} = props.items
    const router = useRouter()
    const shopId = router.query.givenid

    const value = JSON.stringify(categoryProducts)
    // console.log(value)

    function sendData(){
        Router.push({
            pathname: "/[givenid]/categories/[categoryname]", query: { givenid: 'id', categoryname: categoryName, givenProducts: value}
        })
    }

    return <div className="category" onClick={sendData}>
    
        <img src={categoryImage} className="category-img"></img>
        <div className="category-content">
        <h2 className="heading-secondary category-name">{categoryName}</h2>
        <h3 className="heading-tertiary"> {categoryDescription}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When I was trying to not use MongoDB data initially, I was led down the wrong path of trying to get the data through useRouter which will put all of the dummy data into the url. I then tried to stringify it, then parse it open in the [CategoryName] page. This made the url extremely long and there is a way to hide it, by doing something like this:

```
router.push({
    pathname: '/otp-verification',
    query: { email: values.email, password: values.password, phone_number: res.data.phone_number }
}, '/otp-verification')
```

However, this will work on the page load, but once you refresh, it will break.

You also can't stringify then parse the collected info from the [CategoryName] page. What would happen is the "undefined" would get parsed no matter what I did. However after many hours of toil, I uncommented the parsing and console.log and it worked. Something about nextjs loading the page twice, first on first load then putting data I think. Anyway, I didn't try to pursue this any further since it is probably the wrong answer.

Another reason that I am posting this here is that I made a mistake in structuring my stuff initially where [ShopID] is already a dynamic path, because of this I couldn't test it in the [CategoryName]. It seems like I needed the right solution on both at the same time to make it work. I got frustrated enough that I needed to make a post.

Thank you for reading my post. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Bonus Question:
If Mongodb doesn't work, an idea I have is to just put all of the shops info into a cookie/local storage then just access it page to page. Is this a better idea? I don't think it is but maybe this is the path.

Answer (score 0):

So I then realized I could ask chat gpt and it gave me the answer I needed after some tweaking

```
function ShopID({ item }){
const router = useRouter()
const {shopid} = router.query

const { shopCategories } = item.shopData

console.log(shopCategories)


return <Fragment>
    <h1>The shop place</h1>
    <h1>{shopid}</h1>
    <h2>{item.name}</h2>
</Fragment>
}

export default ShopID


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
// Connect to your MongoDB database
const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = client.db();

// Fetch the item from your MongoDB collection based on the ID parameter
const id = new ObjectId(params.shopid);
const item = await db.collection('shops').findOne({ _id: id });

item._id = item._id.toString();

// Close the MongoDB client
client.close();

// Return the item as props
// return { props: { item } }

return {
    props: { item },
    revalidate: 1 // number of seconds to wait before re-generating the page
  };
  }


export async function getStaticPaths() {
// Connect to your MongoDB database
const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = client.db();

// Fetch all item IDs from your MongoDB collection
const items = await db.collection('shops').find({}, { projection: { _id: 1 } }).toArray();

// Generate a list of paths based on the item IDs
const paths = items.map((item) => ({
  params: { shopid: item._id.toString() },
}));

// Close the MongoDB client
client.close();

// Return the list of paths
return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

Comment: While this doesn't fully answer everything I need, it is a good starting point and especially if you are just trying to connect nextjs to mongodb